# type 'MethodChannelFieldValue' is not a subtype of type 'FieldValuePlatform' Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am getting this error `type 'MethodChannelFieldValue' is not a subtype of type 'FieldValuePlatform'` whenever I try to append Firebase array

My code:

```
          DocumentReference reportRef = _store.collection('games').document(pinNum.text);

          reportRef.setData({

            'players': FieldValue.arrayUnion(['hi']),

          }, merge:true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to update in pubspec.yaml firebase core to
`firebase_core: ^0.4.4+2`
and
`cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4`. Basically to the last versions.